# How to programmatically reformat a webpage's text from the browser console

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, console, formatting

I was reading a license agreement and getting annoyed at the long list of definitions with no salient formatting to guide my eye, so I decided to take advantage of their use of quote marks around keywords to bolden all of those keywords.

I ended up using

```
lis = $$("li")
for(var i=0; i<lis.length; i++)
{ lis[i].innerHTML=lis[i].innerHTML.replace(/^(".*?")/,"<b>$1</b>") }
```

Basically, the above code works in the Chrome console to get a list of all `<li>` tags and uses a regex to check if each one starts with a quoted phrase. If it does, we replace that phrase with itself, but surrounded by `<b>` tags. Thus all the quoted bulleted terms in the list become boldened for easy reading. (Really it operates on *all* lists, but I was lazy and this worked on the page I'm looking at.)

My problem is that this was a pain to figure out (especially regex) and feels too verbose for my use case. Isn't there an easier way? Perhaps a JS library I can load that's more suited to reformatting webpages via console?

Answer (score 1):

I regularly use the Google Chrome Developer Tools "Elements" tab to manipulate the look of web-based documentation before saving as a PDF for off-line use.  It's quite easy to quickly locate what you want to hide by adding `display: none`, or whatever you want, to the right places.

Comment: And for tweaks like "bolden quoted text at beginnings of list items" or "turn matching phrases the chosen color, but only if they are in XYZ section of the document"? I like your point and I try to remember to start with the "Elements" tab, but in general I'm talking more advanced tweaking.

Comment: Perhaps adding `id` attributes to things in the "Elements" tab for later use in the console could help.

Comment: @Jallows if you want to replace the above Javascript, you could just add to the stylesheet (in the Elements tab):  `li { font-weight: bold; }`.  For more advanced applications, you can target things quite nicely with CSS these days.

Comment: That doesn't really replace the anything though. The above code restyles regex matches it finds *inside* list items. But thank you.